# Contact Form 7 - Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, datepicker

How do I add an image on date field if I am using Contact Form 7 Datepicker Plugin? The example that I want is on this website, [Jquery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger). This the codes that I did:

```
[date* your-date id:datepicker class:required 15/ " "]
```

On my page theme I add,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true
   });
});
```

But it shows no image on the form and on the console panel has below error,

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
```

Comment: you need to add datepicker jQuery infirst then you can use this datepicker property.

Comment: like this: 
https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js

Comment: If that solve your problem, then you can accept my answer, Cheers. :)

Comment: I add the `jquery.ui.js` and `jquery-ui.css`. Now, the error is `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).foobox is not a function`. The `jquery.min.js` is already added on my header.php page.

Comment: Can you try `jQuery` instead of `$`. so your `document.ready` function be like `jQuery(document).ready(function($){
// here your datepicker function.
})`

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna Thanks for the answer. There is no error now but the image still won't appear

Comment: You can download the image and navigate the image from your project directory.let me know the status.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna Thanks for your ideas and help. I'm able to do it. The problem is the `<script>` that I did was at the last page after the `<body>` tag. I replace it and put it on the `<head>` section. It works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you forgot to include lib js. e.g  `jquery.min.js`,`jquery.ui.js`,`jquery-ui.css`

See the code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true
   });
})
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
```

Also you can see in [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w90a44xL/).